# Show and Hide Menu When you Click on the body

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>    

     $(".pagebg").on('click', function(d) {
        d.preventDefault();
        $("#dnnMenu").removeClass('nav-open');
        $("#google").removeClass('search-open');
    });

    </script>
```

I'm trying to Hide the Menu When I click outside of the div. It does Exactly What I want it to do. But when I click on the links they don't work since when I click on the link it just thinks its the body and hides the menu.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method on the click event of your links/ menu div so it won't execute the click event of the outside container (body)

```
 $(function(){

     $(".someLinks").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       // to do : Hide or show
     });

 });
```